# iPhone: URL scheme not working from mail client

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, url-scheme

I have created URL schemes in my app. I just wanted to open my app from an email. I copy the custom URL scheme **myapp://** in browser and it is opening my app. But when I try opening it from email in iOS mail client, it doesn't open. Is there anything extra needed to be done to open my app from email?

Comment: No there is nothing extra needed. I tested with my app it's ok.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, some email clients just don't handle custom URLs properly.

One solution is to get the browser to open the link instead of the email client. Just host a web-page with a redirect somewhere, and redirect to your custom link.

For example, a php page:

```
<?php
    $arg = $_GET["arg"];
    $url = "myapp://host?arg={$arg}";
    header("Location: {$url}");
?>
```

Then put a normal link in the email:

`http://www.example.com/openurl.php?arg=123`

Answer (score 0):

In e-mail body, you should write content in html format. Here you require a hyperlink so there should be `<a href> ... </a>`

For example:

```
<a href="myapp://">Launch MyApp</a>
```

Hope this helps.